# Android ProgressDialog Styling not working right

Tags: android, dialog, styles

I have followed the style guide as best I can, and I cannot explain why I get gray boxes on my styled dialog when using this code:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Logging into CRM Suite", "Please wait...", true);
```

[image]

I don't know why or where  how how those gray boxes are coming from.

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#d8ebff</item> <!-- correct, must be here, KEY SCAN FIN, etc -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarStyle</item> <!-- required, correct -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#d8ebff</item> <!-- global text color, correct -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> <!-- does nothing -->
    <item name="android:background">#436072</item> <!-- sets global background, breaks dialog shadow -->

  </style>

  <style name="actionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
      <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/actionBarTitleTextStyle</item> <!-- required, correct -->
      <item name="android:background">#436072</item> <!-- blue divider if not set -->      
  </style>

  <style name="actionBarTitleTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#d8ebff</item> <!-- correct -->
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item> <!--  correct -->
  </style>  

</resources>
```

Comment: You need to show your layout XML.

Comment: Updated. Thank you. While this does not show anything about the AlertDialog title style, this is the minimal style that is needed to accomplish what is shown. I tried _MANY_ variations to get those gray sections to go away, but none were successful, so I didn't include them here.

Comment: I have deleted my answer to this question, as it is now clear from comments to it that the asker was actually using ProgressDialog, not AlertDialog. I have modified the question's title to indicate that, and I have added additional information from the comments.

Comment: Progress Dialog is a subclas of AlertDialog, therfore styling a Alert dialog should also carry through tot he progress dialogs, no?